# Remodel recessed light on drywall seam

Tags: drywall, recessed-lighting

One of the spots where I would like to install a remodel-type 5" round recessed light, is right on top of the drywall seam in my ceiling. I'm a little hesitant to put it there because the ceiling must bear the weight of the light fixture. Will it be okay? Should I try to reinforce it somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no issue with the weight-bearing capacity of properly seamed drywall.

It may be a little more difficult to cut the hole due to the joint, but there's no structural defect of note to supporting a lightweight light fixture designed to be supported by drywall.